# matlab create histogram from the map

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a map in matlab :

```
containers.Map handle
Package: containers

Properties:
      Count: 3
    KeyType: 'char'
  ValueType: 'double'
```

for example:

```
keys(dict)
ans = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'
values(dict)
ans = 
    [1]    [1]    [2]
```

Is there an easy way to build a histogram plot from this map.
What I need is something like this:[image]

I tried something like this: `hist(keys(dict), values(dict))`, but the problem is that `keys(dict)` and `values(dict)` is a cell and hist is only working with vectors.

Is there an easy way to create a histogram out of a map, or I should iterate through keys and values?

Comment: `cell2mat(values(dict))`?

Answer (score 2):

Just found the right answer:

```
bar( cell2mat( values(dict) ) )
```

Trying to find how to add a nice legend to the bar...

Answer (score 0):

To add the keys as x labels use:

```
set(gca,'XTick',[1:length(keys(dict))])
set(gca,'xticklabel', keys(dict))
```